# Win32Exception when trying to run a .bat file as a specific user

Tags: c#-4.0, permissions, asp.net-4.0

I'm trying to run a batch file on a server from an ASP.NET page. The batch file needs to run under a certain user account in order to be successful.

My code to run the batch file **without** it running under a specific account works fine, (when it runs under SYSTEM), but the batch file fails to execute successfully.

What I need to be able to do is run it under a specific (Administrator) account on the server, but when I add the code to run under this account, I get an exception:

> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception
>   (0x80004005): Access is denied    at
>   System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo
>   startInfo)    at
>   System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()

The account definetely exists (it's the only one on that machine) and has administritive rights. Also, if I login to the physical machine and run the .bat file manually under the account, it works fine.

Here's my code:

```
Process m_oProc = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo oInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(batchFileLocation);

oInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(batchFileLocation);
oInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
oInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
oInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

// ------ This code seems to cause the exception ------ //

string prePassword = "myadminpassword";
SecureString passwordSecure = new SecureString();
char[] passwordChars = prePassword.ToCharArray();
foreach (char c in passwordChars)
{
     passwordSecure.AppendChar(c);
}

oInfo.UserName = "admin";
oInfo.Password = passwordSecure;

// ---------------------------------------------------- //

m_oProc.StartInfo = oInfo;
if (m_oProc.Start())
{
      log.Info("Debug: Process has started successfully");
}
else
{
      log.Error("Some error occured starting the process.");
}
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this is an internally facing application, I just set the Identity of the Application Pool to the account I want to run under - this resolved my issues.